# Application Ionic being closed to open external URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I come once again request your help for my problem, I have a made in ionic application that takes some latitudes and longitudes saved in a database and then I recover them on the screen and inject them into a url that opens the application waze so the driver can navigate to these cordenadas, the application works fine without any error the only problem is that the application is shut down when the waze is open, I wonder if anyone can help me avoid the application to when closed to end the use of waze application returned normally already required.

```
$scope.openwaze = function(){
window.open('http://waze.to/?ll=' + lat + ',' + long + '&navigate=yes', '_system', 'location=no'); return false;
}
```

It works to open but closes the application ionic

Comment: Please add the code you use to open the url.

Comment: added the code I use to open, it works great to open but when I finish navigating the waze application of ionic is closed.

Comment: Did you install the in app browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution of my another question and now works for me my application is not closed.

[How to use cordova-waze-navigator plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176462/how-to-use-cordova-waze-navigator-plugin/36181089#36181089)