# How to use cordova-waze-navigator plugin

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How to use this plugin

https://github.com/adaltojunior86/cordova-waze-navigator

I've looked all over the internet but have not yet found a way to use github has nothing explaining how to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is there is no documentation for that plugin, so if you want to use it, you'll have to look at the source code, which implies a usage of:

```
WazeNavigator.navigateByPosition({
    lat: 50, // latitude
    lng: -4 // longitude
});
```

Or you could use the updated version 3 of [phonegap-launch-navigator](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator) plugin, 
which now supports launching Waze, along with many other navigation apps and **does** have documentation.

Comment: Hello I installed the plugin but I'm getting this error when trying tocompile

Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\mellevet\platforms\android\gr
adlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\mellevet\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch
=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
 code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: When you say "the plugin", I assume you mean `cordova-waze-navigator`? If so, I'd try `phonegap-launch-navigator` instead, which is documented and better supported. Otherwise, if you really want to use the Waze one, you'll need post the entire verbose android log output - what you've put in the comment isn't enough to diagnose the problem. And you probably want to open it as an issue the `cordova-waze-navigator` github repo.

Comment: Great Friend solution works like a glove, I had trouble rotating in my ionic application even following the example but it was enough I remove and add the android platform again and it worked for me thanks muitop you deserve 10 stars wowww